# Is it bad practice to use gksu when writing code in development?

Tags: permissions, root, c++, gksu, gksudo

I am writing a C++ application that needs to access the serial port and use the mount command, both needing root to be performed.

In the end the application will be run as root on a device, but I am wondering if it **is bad practice to start the IDE with gksu while in development mode?** I am afraid that a mistake in the code could damage the machine and also it adds extra steps when cross-compiling the app, since I first need to chown it.

I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/read-write-to-a-serial-port-without-root) article that explains how to use the serial port without root, and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96625/allow-non-superusers-to-mount-any-filesystem) that explains how to use mount without root, but I am wondering if I should follow these recommandation or if there is another way.

Comment: If you can do something without having root, then why use root?

Comment: Because on every machine that I work, I will have to add myself to the group that owns the serial ports and for the mount part I will have to change the code.

Comment: Well, what's your priority here? Security or ease of use?

Comment: I would say both, leaning on security. I know how to achieve either of them, but was wondering if there is a way to get both.

Comment: OK... How about just scripting the mount and group changing parts? Then you can use `sudo` for exactly what it is needed for, and a setup script shouldn't be that difficult or cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, probably this is the way to go, but I am not sure what you mean by scripting the mount part?

Comment: You said something about mounting and having to change the code for that. I wonder why that has to be done within the code.

Comment: The mount should be done in the code. For the device I am writing the code, when a removable media is inserted it is not automatically mounted, so I have to mount it from the code. What I meant by changing the code is to use `pmount` or something similar, as stated in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, you should probably develop this from a live DVD/USB so that you don't have to worry about making a mistake. Push your work to a remote server just in case and then do all of your development on the live device so if something goes wrong, you can just wipe it and reinstall it without losing any personal data.